# Extraer nombre de columna de un valor máximo por fila de una dataframe en python

Tags: python-2.7, lista, dataframe

Buen dia a todos,

Tengo el siguiente dataframe y quiero extraer las columnas según el valor máximo de cada fila, como se muestra a continuación.

```
     E   D   C  B  A  A1
0   27  17  20  3  2   0
1   19  20  13  2  0   0
2   28  22  23  5  2   0
3   42  14  18  3  1   0
4   34  19  12  4  3   0
5   34  20  15  0  1   0
6   32  28  16  4  3   1
7   19  23  17  5  0   0
8   37  17  18  4  2   1
9   33  22  14  1  1   0
10  53  24  16  5  0   0
11  18  17  13  0  0   0
12  33  17  15  4  1   0
13  33  22  12  2  2   0
14  20  19  12  2  1   0
```

Y requiero obtener la siguiente lista:

```
[E,D,E,E,E,E,E,D,E,E,E,E,E,E,E]
```

Esta lista representa la columna donde se encuentra el valor máximo de cada fila.

```
[27, 20, 28, 42, 34, 34, 32, 23, 37, 33, 53, 18, 33, 33, 20]
```

La lista de valores son los máximos extraídos de cada fila del dataframe.

He intentado con el siguiente código pero no me ha funcionado.

```
Destra =[]
for i in range(15):
    DFi = df[i:i+1]
    Destra.append(DFi.values.max()) 

VEs = []    
for j in range(15):
    DFj = df[j:j+1]
    sDF = DFj.loc[::] == Destra[j]
    Vj = sDF.columns.get_values()[True]
    VEs.append(Vj)
VEs
```

Por que cuyo resultado es:

```
['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

Y no es lo que estoy buscando.

Gracias por su colaboración.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Pandas tiene el método `.idxmax()` que te devuelve el índice del máximo (por filas o por columnas, según su parámetro `axis`). Esto es justo lo que necesitas:

```
>>> VEs = df.idxmax(axis=1)
>>> Destra = df.max(axis=1)

>>> VEs.values
array(['E', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'], dtype=object)
>>> Destra.values
array([27, 20, 28, 42, 34, 34, 32, 23, 37, 33, 53, 18, 33, 33, 20])
```

Si los quieres como lista puedes usar  `list(VEs.values)`

Comment: Si es lo que buscaba muchas gracias por su respuesta. Saludos